# how to handle MFA in C# selenium testing

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Below are the steps to over come:

1. Browser is asking for email address
2. Once I input and click next, it is taking me to a new browser where I have to select Phone or SMS options.
3. Once I select SMS option, it is asking me to input the key
4. Once I input key, it is validating and taking me to application home page.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest disabling the MFA for the account, or whitelist the account so that it would be always the same key. Anyway, this has nothing to do with Selenium but you need to change the AUT to meet these requirements.